# Cookie Based Authentication Not Working On Ionic/Angular App

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, ionic-framework

I am trying to convert an existing website into a hybrid app using Ionic framework. On login, the server sends a session cookie for me to use on my other calls, however the cookie is not saved on the browser which results in login redirects on access attempts. I use the following function on login submits.

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
let url = 'http://localhost/api/auth/login';

var data = 'username=' + this.credentials.username + '&password=' + 
            this.credentials.password + '&captchaResponse=';

this.http.post(url, data, {headers: headers})
.subscribe(data => {
    if(data.json().result == 'success'){
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(FaultsPage);
    } else {
        alert('Wrong username or password');
    }       
}, err => {
    console.error('Error: ', err);
    alert('Something went wrong, try again later');
});
```

Server accepts the credentials and sends a session cookie. Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is set to true on server-side.

I also tried to manually set the cookie, however I cannot access the Set-Cookie header.

My Ionic version is 3.4.0 and using Angular 4.2.2.

Comment: Edit: The URL is on localhost because the website's server does not support CORS and I've implemented CORS functionality on a local copy of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. Because both origin and destination URLs were localhost, the browser thought that it was generating its own cookie, while ignoring the port number. To solve it, I changed the destination URL's domain from localhost to the computer's username. In addition, the login request also needs to set withCredentials to true.